# sys.dm_exec_requests - start_time

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I have the following query that tells me the status of queries in a database I'm responsible for (although I am not a DBA).

```
SELECT 
     T3.FullStatement as FullSQLStatement
    ,T3.ExecutingStatement
    ,req.session_id as SessionId
    ,T2.login_name as LoginName
    ,command as SQLCommand
    ,start_time as StartTime
    ,DateDiff(MINUTE,start_time,GetDate()) as ElapsedTimeMinutes
    ,req.status as QueryStatus
    ,req.wait_type as WaitType
    ,req.wait_time as WaitTimeMs
    ,blocking_session_id as BlockingSessionId
    ,req.row_count as [RowCount]
    ,req.cpu_time as CpuTimeMs
    ,req.total_elapsed_time as TotalElapsedTimeMs
    ,SubString(sqltext.TEXT,req.statement_start_offset,req.statement_end_offset-req.statement_start_offset)
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
    Inner Join sys.dm_exec_sessions T2 ON T2.session_id = req.session_id
    Cross Apply dbo.GetExecutingSQLStatement (req.session_id) T3
    Cross Apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
where req.database_id = 5
Order By 6 Desc
```

It generates output that looks, partly, as follows:

[image]
Even though it doesn't show very well in the example I've included, the start_time is the start time of the full statement and not the executing portion of the statement. Is there somewhere I can get the start time of the executing portion along with the start time of the full statement. This is important to me because, obviously, a full statement could have many individual queries.

Answer (score 8):

<del>At the moment this does not seem like a possible value to get, which is unfortunate as this does seem like a handy value to have.</del>

Ok, I did find it (mostly). There is a `last_execution_time` field in the [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) DMV, though that DMV comes with the following warning:

> An initial query of **sys.dm_exec_query_stats** might produce inaccurate results if there is a workload currently executing on the server. More accurate results may be determined by rerunning the query.

Also, I am not sure how the value of `last_execution_time` is affected by multiple concurrent executions of the exact same SQL across multiple sessions since `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` is per query batch, *not* per session.

Below is what I have so far. There is maybe one thing I kinda want to clean up, but this should already account for the first query in a batch which will not have a corresponding entry in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` since that gets populated (ideally, but not always in a timely manner) after the current statement / query completes. And it seems to work for single-query batches, so try it out.

```sql
SELECT req.session_id AS [SessionID],
       req.start_time AS [BatchStartTime],
       req.total_elapsed_time as [BatchMilliseconds], --[TotalElapsedTimeMs],
       CASE WHEN stat.last_execution_time IS NOT NULL THEN
                DATEADD(MILLISECOND,
                        (stat.last_elapsed_time / 1000.0),
                        stat.last_execution_time)
            ELSE req.start_time END AS [StatementStartTime],
       DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,
                CASE WHEN stat.last_execution_time IS NOT NULL THEN
             DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (stat.last_elapsed_time / 1000.0),
                stat.last_execution_time)
                  ELSE req.start_time END, GETDATE()) AS [StatementMilliseconds],
       T2.login_name AS [LoginName],
       req.command AS [SQLCommand],
       req.[status] AS [QueryStatus],
       req.wait_type AS [WaitType],
       req.wait_time AS [WaitTimeMs],
       blocking_session_id AS [BlockingSessionId],
       req.row_count AS [RowCount],
       req.cpu_time AS [CpuTimeMs],
       sqltext.[text] AS [QueryBatch],
       SUBSTRING(sqltext.[text],
                 req.statement_start_offset / 2,
                 CASE req.statement_end_offset
                      WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(sqltext.[text])
                      ELSE (req.statement_end_offset - req.statement_start_offset) / 2
                 END) AS [CurrentQuery]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions T2
        ON T2.session_id = req.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats stat
        ON stat.[sql_handle] = req.[sql_handle]
       AND stat.statement_end_offset = (req.statement_start_offset - 2)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.[sql_handle]) sqltext
-- WHERE req.session_id = 56
ORDER BY req.start_time;
```

I have been testing with your query (slightly modified) and the following SQL running in another tab / session (the `TOP(1)`, `TOP(2)`, etc, and `10.1`, `10.2`, etc on the `WAITFOR` times are to make it easily visible which statement is being processed when looking at the current statement field):

```sql
SELECT GETDATE() AS [StartTime];
GO
SELECT TOP(1) [name] FROM sys.objects;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.1';

SELECT TOP(2) [name] FROM sys.objects;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.2';

SELECT TOP(3) [name] FROM sys.objects;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.3';

SELECT TOP(4) [name] FROM sys.objects;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.4';
```

Then just run your query several times and it is pretty clear that `dm_exec_requests.start_time` and `dm_exec_sessions.last_request_start_time` are:

- the same value, and
- do not change at all during the execution of that batch.

I did try getting the execution plan via `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(req.plan_handle, req.statement_end_offset, req.statement_end_offset) tplan`, but that was `NULL` so not very helpful.

---

In order to test with your query, I had to remove the first two columns and the reference to the `dbo.GetExecutingSQLStatement` function. This is probably something you could also get rid of since you have that logic in this query already via `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.[sql_handle])`. You just need to make the following three changes:

- `T3.FullStatement` (Select field # 1) becomes `sqltext.[text]`
- `T3.ExecutingStatement` (Select field # 2) becomes `SUBSTRING(sqltext.[text], req.statement_start_offset / 2, CASE req.statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN LEN(sqltext.[text]) ELSE (req.statement_end_offset - req.statement_start_offset) / 2 END)`
- Remove the `SUBSTRING` (your current last field). If you look closely at the `SUBSTRING` I am suggesting directly above, it is essentially what you had at the end there, expect it corrects for two mistakes:

  - Your SUBSTRING did not account for when there was only 1 query in the batch, in which case `statement_end_offset` is `-1` and your substring gets an error
  - Your SUBSTRING did not account for the translation of double-byte byte count into character count.

But I digress.

---