# Is total_elapsed_time in DMV sys.dm_exec_requests completely inaccurate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dmv

I am running SQL Server 2012 and am trying to put some queries together for monitoring using the DMVs.  However, when looking at the `total_elapsed_time` field in the `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV, the numbers look way off.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT
  session_id, RunTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  start_time, total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = 284;

session_id  RunTime                 start_time              total_elapsed_time
284         2016-04-07 16:14:03.690 2016-04-07 16:08:14.587 1419976
```

By my calculations*, the elapsed time should be around around 349,103 -- not 1,419,976.  That's off by over a factor of 4.

<sub>* From the difference, in milliseconds, between the current time and the *start_time* i.e.

    `SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '2016-04-07T16:08:14.587', '2016-04-07T16:14:03.690');`</sub>

Here's the server info:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5592.0 (X64) 
    Apr 17 2015 15:18:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/sys-dm-exec-requests-start-time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a bug that aggregates the time in a parallel operation.  This is fixed in 2014.

The *total_elapsed_time* will be correct for a particular parallel query in a batch until it moves on to the next statement in the batch, then the *total_elapsed_time* will explode by the DOP.

#### Example

Run this in one query window:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
JOIN Production.Product p ON sod.ProductID = p.ProductID
ORDER BY Style 

waitfor delay '00:00:15'
```

Run this in a second:

```
select 
    DATEDIFF(ms, start_time, getdate()) ActualElapsedTime,
    total_elapsed_time from sys.dm_exec_requests
where session_id = <your session_id for the above batch>
```

The two values will be close to identical until SQL Server moves to the `WAITFORDELAY` statement, then you should see the *total_elapsed_time* explode (assuming the first query has a parallel plan as it does on my server).

I remember working on this for a customer a few years ago. Found the bug in the internal database (I am a Microsoft Premier Developer Consultant), but no public reference.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it could also be an bug/issue with the DMV. There is a Connect bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/783674/sys-dm-exec-requests-total-elapsed-time) of this same kind of inaccuracy.  The suggested workaround is to use

```
GETDATE() - sys.dm_exec_requests.start_time
```

instead of *total_elapsed_time*. The issue is resolved in SQL Server 2014. To quote the comment on the Connect item by "Nathan (MSFT)":

> The issue with *sys.dm_exec_requests.total_elapsed_time* isn't specific to `RESTORE` operations; it has also been observed with `UPDATE STATISTICS` as well. This issue will not be resolved in SQL Server 2008 R2. [...] The issue is resolved in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked a couple servers and on the background requests observed a drift of about 14s over 2 months.

However that aside, the only significant difference I can see on other requests is where the spid has gone into a SLEEPING state. I suspect that this value does not increment while in that state; but I haven't been able to force a query into SLEEPING in order to test it. (WAITFOR goes to suspended rather than sleeping).

There may be other causes but I haven't found any yet. You could rule this one out by monitoring your query to make sure it doesn't go to SLEEPING state.